# Refresh div content to check status of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page and inside it i have a button `<a href...>`. My problem is that when this button is clicked, it changes the text in the button. Until here, all is working.

Now my problem. This page is multi user page, so I need to refresh `<div>` content every period of time to show other users if this button already clicked or not.

I tried many javascript and jquery codes but I can´t update the button. I can update div to write some text using `$("#divid").text('Random msg');` but this do not change the button.

The button is inside `<div>` tag but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will wait 1 second before changing the text inside of the button:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("btnid").innerHTML = "Random msg";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <button id="btnid">Not clicked</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but maybe you dont understand my problem... Change button text is working what i need is set a interval to refresh content in all user browsers that is connected to the page and if button is clicked for me and text is button on, all users must see button on, if button's text is button off all users must see button off understand?

Comment: You may want to try combining `setTimeout` with some sort of web request like `$.ajax`.

Comment: Ok, this i know, but i dont know what code could i use. Can you give an exemple?

Comment: @BrMyAppsAD I've given you all the resources to answer your own question. Take it upon yourself to not use StackOverflow as a crutch but rather a last resort.

Comment: you could, at least, be more specif 'bout what function of $.ajax to use? I saw many but i couldn´t take what to use...

Comment: The main two types are GET & POST. You'll probably want to use GET for something like this.